# unable to use/load mscomct2.ocx controls in vb6 ide windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows, vb6, mscomct2.ocx

I get the below error trying to refer the mscomct2.ocx file, in VB6 IDE on a Windows 7 32 bit PC. The IDE is run on elevated mode.

I tried many solutions from SO and other sources, but nothing works for me.

1. unregistered and re registered from a elevated command prompt
2. deleted and restored this file from backup and ms sites.
3. tried finding if duplicate mscomct2.ocx are registered in other paths. but only 1 file under windows\system32 is found in the PC

Any quick help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the 5.0 version of them?

5.0 offers the benefit of working with Windows XP/Vista/7/8 themes.

I currently am able to use all common controls.  So it's likely just a matter of re-registering the ocx file:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146219

That is, running in command line:

```
CD C:\Windows\SysWOW64
regsvr32 /s mscomct2.ocx
```

Comment: trying to do this... but listview attributes differ betwee v5 and v6... will update...

Comment: with no other options to make this work, have reverted to version 5 as suggested by @phoenixx_2....

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with VB6 in Win7 64bit. Tried re-registering (CMD.exe in admin mode) to no avail. Ran VB6 in admin mode and it had no problem adding the control.